# A problem about volume integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $F=(y,xz,1)$ be the vector field on $\mathcal{R}^3$.

Let $t\in(-1,1)$, $S_t$ be a family of surfaces defined by $x^2+y^2+(tz)^2=1,\ z\geq0$ with the unit normal vector $n$ on $S_t$ so that $n\cdot(0,0,1)>0$.
Define $I(t)=\int\int_{S_t}\text{curl}\ F\cdot n\ dS_t$.

Compute $I'(0)$.

I tried to evaluate $I(t)$ through Gauss divergence theorem, but the divergence of curl is zero.

Original source:
[image]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The unit normal vector doesn't make sense since for $t=0$ we have a cylinder with an open top and bottom in the $z$ direction.

Comment: I think you might have one or more typos in your question, otherwise it is trivial. Please check your source again because currently the integral is a constant value for all $t$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I put the original problem here. I'm not sure what I ignored.

Comment: I see, the original problem itself is poorly defined. The integral diverges for $t=0$. If you were to regularize it by the usual means, we still get that $I(t)=-\pi$ for all $t$. Take from that what you will.